# How do I use gl.h in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to understand why this program will compile in C but not C++ and why `extern "C" { }` doesn't seem to help.

This short program doesn't actually do anything, but shows by example that there is a difference in the compilation when it is C vs C++.

```
    #include <GL/gl.h>
    int main() {
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glUseProgram(0);
        glEnd();
        return 0;
    }
```

When you save that as ex.c and compile it with `gcc ex.c -lGL -o ex` it compiles and links as expected.

When you save it as ex.cpp and compile it with `gcc ex.cpp -lGL -o ex` you get a compiler error:

```
error: ‘glUseProgram’ was not declared in this scope
```

Note that it does not complain about glBegin, glEnd, or GL_POLYGON. In fact, you can comment out the glUseProgram line and it compiles just fine as a cpp program.

Now, why can't I wrap the program in `extern "C"` like so:

```
    extern "C" {
        #include <GL/gl.h>
        int main() {
            glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
            glUseProgram(0);
            glEnd();
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Doing so still leads to the same compiler error. My understanding of `extern "C"` is incomplete.

Ultimately I need to understand what is wrong because I am trying to write a C++ program that uses many of the GL functions that apparently won't compile in C++.

**How do I use gl.h in a C++ program?**

---

To address a few of the comments: I am using Mesa on X11. glUseProgram definition is in glext.h which is included via gl.h. I have already written a C++ program using OpenGL (actually GLES) on a raspi. converting it to X11 is proving to be a non-trivial matter.

Comment: Can you post the section of `glUseProgram` in the header file?

Comment: The appropriate thing to do when you don't understand a point of syntax is to read a few articles on it and get more familiar.

Comment: I don't think you can find `glUseProgram` in your `GL/gl.h`. Try looking for it in `GL/glext.h`

Comment: Mine's in `GL/glcorearb.h` under `#ifdef GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES`. However, it says not to include it if already including `gl.h` or `glext.h`, yet neither of those include it either directly nor indirectly.

Comment: @chris, i haven't found any clues in what ive read. when i bring an issue like this to the community its because documentation has failed to make it clear. if you know of an article, please post it.

Comment: Placing `#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` before the include directive solves your problem (at least it's solved on my laptop). However I don't think it is expected to be like this. Maybe a bug I guess.

Comment: @Octopus, I wouldn't know; I don't use OGL. I was just observing my copy of the files.

Comment: @starrify See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I've commented, placing `#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` before the include directive solves your problem.

See [the OpenGL ABI for Linux](http://www.opengl.org/registry/ABI/):

> Normally, prototypes are present in the header files, but are not visible due to conditional compilation. To define prototypes as well as typedefs, the application must #define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES prior to including gl.h or glx.h. (Note: consistency suggests using GLX_GLXEXT_PROTOTYPES for glxext.h - TBD).

This is usually done by something like `GLUT` or `GLEW` in their header files, so if you're working with them it's typically not needed to defined the macro yourself -- however be sure to include their headers *before* the `GL/gl.h`

**EDITED:** The reason why `glBegin` works fine while there's problem with `glUseProgram` is that `glBegin` comes with the very first draft of OpenGL while `glUseProgram` had been an extension and hasn't get introduced until OpenGL 2.0.

**EDITED:**
Let's be more specific: why it works with C but not C++? First of all, there is no `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` defined in neither C or C++ version. You could test it with simply some code like this:

```
#ifdef GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
puts("macro detected");
#endif
```

The reason, however, is in C it's allowed that a symbol of function could get no definition at all (which would be assumed as all its parameters are int and also returns an int), while in C++ it's not allowed.

Comment: glUseProgram was introduced with 3.0, not 4.0.

Comment: @Domi Thank you very much for pointing out my typo.. However my `glext.h` suggests that it was introduced in OpenGL 2.0 since the prototype is guarded by `#ifndef GL_VERSION_2_0`.

Comment: oh right, shaders came with 2.0. However, the FFP deprecation came with 3.0 :)

Comment: Yes, GLSL was formally introduced into OpenGL with 2.0, so `glUseProgram (...)` requires 2.0. Prior to this, as far back as implementations of OpenGL 1.4 supported GLSL through the ARB extension, which used slightly different naming for a lot of functions (e.g. `glUseProgramObjectARB (...)`) - not particularly important or relevant, but a fun bit of trivia while we are discussing ***when*** GLSL was actually introduced :P

Answer (score 4):

The quickest way to get it working, is to define `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` before the `gl.h` include :

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include <GL/gl.h>
```

in order to expose the function prototypes.

The reason it still works in C without the prototypes (function declaratons), is because C is not as strict as C++ about needing the function declaration for a called function (it'll implicitly assume a `int fun()` function declaration).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do, is check if you have the various `gl` header files. If you have them already, check if you have the needed native files (.dll) and be sure that you load them into your program/project.

### Get GLEW (OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library)

For your own sake get something like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/). Why? because by default all the GL function aren't called `glUseProgram` and such. By default on my computer (Windows7) `glUseProgram()` is actually called `PFNGLUSEPROGRAMPROC`.

Thereby to get those "ugly" things replaced by the more readable once, simply get GLEW.

You could also simply `#define` all those "ugly" things away, though that will be A LOT OF WORK. So again it would be easier to get something like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I explained that I have boiled this down for simplicity. The issue is not one of the use of the functions it is in why some of them compile in C++ and some of them don't. This was not meant to be a working program and that was clearly stated in the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: My first paragraph of my answer and maybe my GLEW bit, should solve you program, as doing that works for me and always have. ... I removed the unnecessary stuff.